# Как перенаправить пользователя по cookie если он уже заходил?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, cookie

Смысл такой, пользователь заходит на мою страницу, если он заходит первый раз, тогда страница открывается, если он зашел второй раз, тогда происходит redirect на другую страницу.

Ниже приведен пример если заходят из поисковой системы.

Как переделать чтобы у пользователя сохранялись куки, и если он зайдет второй раз не важно каким способом, то его перекидывало на другую страницу пока живи куки?

```
 if(document.referrer){
        if (!document.referrer.includes(document.domain)){
            if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)thehuub\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, '$1') !== 'true') {
                document.location.href='http://test.com';
                document.cookie = 'thehuub=true; expires=Fri, 20 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT';
            }
        }
    }
```

**Будьте добры,помочь в данном вопросе.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз в вопросе указана метка `php`, то предложу свой вариант, ей соответствующий.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["ENTER"]) || isset($_COOKIE["ENTER"])) {
//Если пользователь зашёл второй раз, не закрыв браузер.
//Если пользователь заходит второй раз из вновь открытого браузера (если cookie не были удалены).
    header('Location: http://ехаmрlе.соm/аnоthеr.html');
} else {
    $_SESSION["ENTER"] = "YES";
    setcookie("ENTER", "YES");
};
?>
```

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо большое !